# How can I generate a quarterly date sequence in Java?

Tags: java, r, date

I'm trying to create a function in Java that generates a quarterly date sequence, given a start and end date.

In R, for example, I can do this as follows:

```
generateQuarterlySequence = function(startDate, endDate)
{
  require(zoo)

  # Generate date sequence
  dateSequence = seq.Date(from = as.Date(startDate), 
                          to = as.Date(endDate), 
                          by = "quarter")

  # Convert to quarters
  dateSequence = as.yearqtr(dateSequence, format = "%Y-%m-%d") 

  # Get rid of extra white space
  dateSequence = gsub(" ", "", dateSequence) 

  return(dateSequence)

}

generateQuarterlySequence(startDate = "2017-06-30", endDate = "2017-12-31")
[1] "2017Q2" "2017Q3" "2017Q4"
```

Any rock stars care to show how this is done in Java? You'd be making this Java beginner very happy!

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class of ThreeTen-Extra.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that in a comment I suggested [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/). However, here’s a solution using pure `java.time` as built-in in Java 8 and later and available in Java 6 and 7 through [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

```
public static List<String> generateQuarterlySequence(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    // first truncate startDate to first day of quarter
    int startMonth = startDate.getMonthValue();
    startMonth-= (startMonth - 1) % 3;
    startDate = startDate.withMonth(startMonth).withDayOfMonth(1);

    DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuQQQ", Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<String> quarterSequence = new ArrayList<>();

    // iterate thorough quarters
    LocalDate currentQuarterStart = startDate;
    while (! currentQuarterStart.isAfter(endDate)) {
        quarterSequence.add(currentQuarterStart.format(quarterFormatter));
        currentQuarterStart = currentQuarterStart.plusMonths(3);
    }
    return quarterSequence;
}
```

Trying it with your example arguments:

```
    System.out.println(generateQuarterlySequence(LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 30),
            LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 31)));
```

prints

```
[2017Q2, 2017Q3, 2017Q4]
```

Comment: Good answer for all people who don't want or cannot afford a 3rd-party library (suggestions either from Basil Bourque or in my answer).

Comment: @Ole V.V., awesome answer. This worked like a charm when I plugged it into my script!!

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
YearQuarter.from( LocalDate.parse( "2017-06-30" ) )
           .plusQuarters( 1 )
```

## `org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter`

The other [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47602890/642706) using java.time is good. Alternatively, here is code using the [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that extends java.time with additional functionality. If you are doing much work with quarters, you will find it well worth the bother to add the ThreeTen-Extra library to your project.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2017-06-30" );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "2017-12-31" );
```

From those, determine the year-quarter in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) calendar system, meaning Q1 is January to March, Q2 is April to June, Q3 is July to September and Q4 is October to December.

```
YearQuarter yqStart = YearQuarter.from( start );
YearQuarter yqStop = YearQuarter.from( stop );
```

Collect the series of quarters as a `List`.

```
int initialCapacity = ( int ) ( ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( start , stop ) + 1 ) * 4;
List < YearQuarter > quarters = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );
```

Loop each quarter, incrementing by calling `plusQuarters`, and collect into the list.

```
YearQuarter yq = yqStart;
while ( ! yq.isAfter( yqStop ) )
{
    quarters.add( yq );
    // Setup next loop.
    yq = yq.plusQuarters( 1 );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( start + "/" + stop + " = " + quarters );
```

> 2017-06-30/2017-12-31 = [2017-Q2, 2017-Q3, 2017-Q4]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Basil, thanks so much for taking your time to answer my question. I'll keep note of this in case I start working with quarters more often!

Answer (score 2):

My library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) enables following very simple solution using the streaming-API of Java-8:

```
DateInterval range = 
    DateInterval.between(
        PlainDate.of(2017, 6, 30),
        PlainDate.of(2017, 12, 31)
    );
range.stream(Duration.of(1, CalendarUnit.QUARTERS))
    .map(CalendarQuarter::from)
    .forEach(System.out::println);

// 2017-Q2
// 2017-Q3
// 2017-Q4
```

The code first constructs a [date interval](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/DateInterval.html) which is streamable. You can define a stream by iteratively adding a quarter year to the start date of the interval. The map-operation maps the generated (gregorian) dates in the stream to the desired year-quarter, called [CalendarQuarter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarQuarter.html) in Time4J and finally calls its toString()-method to produce the output.

If you prefer to eliminate the hyphen in the output then you can either apply a simple string-replace-method in another map-method or use a suitable [formatter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html) (which should best be stored in a static constant since it is immutable):

```
ChronoFormatter<CalendarQuarter> f =
  ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
      "uuuuQQQ", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, CalendarQuarter.chronology());
range.stream(Duration.of(1, CalendarUnit.QUARTERS))
    .map(CalendarQuarter::from)
    .map(cq -> f.format(cq))
    .forEach(System.out::println);

// 2017Q2
// 2017Q3
// 2017Q4
```

The last piece of code could even be simplified by leaving out the intermediate type `CalendarQuarter` because a gregorian date (here: `PlainDate`) can also be formatted as quarterly date in the same way (one map-operation less).

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer my question. Your library looks good!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using plain Java 8 streams and java.time api:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 25);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2002, 4, 1);
    Stream<LocalDate> quarterBounds = Stream.iterate(
            startDate.with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1), date -> date.plus(3, MONTHS));

    DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuQQQ", Locale.ENGLISH);
    quarterBounds
            .filter(d -> !endDate.isBefore(d))
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .map(quarterFormatter::format)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Sample output:

```
2000-10-01
2000Q4
2001-01-01
2001Q1
2001-04-01
2001Q2
2001-07-01
2001Q3
2001-10-01
2001Q4
2002-01-01
2002Q1
2002-04-01
2002Q2
```

Via [How to get the first date and last date of current quarter in java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493649/how-to-get-the-first-date-and-last-date-of-current-quarter-in-java-util-date?rq=1#comment95686234_50702885).